# Replace string with template output in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, pelican

In *Pelican*, a page's content is passed to the *Jinja2* template as `page.content`.  Let's assume that `page.content` contains a string `{REPLACEME}`.  How can I now replace this string `{REPLACEME}` with the result from some template logic, say

```
{% for pub in publications %}
  {% set key, year, text, bibtex, doi, url, pdf, slides, poster = pub %}
  {% if "%s"|format(year) == "%s"|format(yr) %}
    <li id="{{ key }}">{{ text }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The idea is that I want to use template logic to render a list of items, but still be able to decide where this list should appear within the `page.content`.

I know that there is a `replace()` [filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-filters%20filter) in *Jinja2*, but I cannot figure out how to make the `new` argument contain the template ouptut from above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there's *macros* in Jinja2.

```
{% macro bibtex_rendered() -%}
  {% for pub in publications %}
    {% set key, year, text, bibtex, doi, url, pdf, slides, poster = pub %}
    {% if "%s"|format(year) == "%s"|format(yr) %}
      <li id="{{ key }}">{{ text }}</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{%- endmacro %}
```

Then I can use the defined macro in my call to `replace`:

```
    {{ page.content | replace("{PUBLICATIONS}", bibtex_rendered()) }}
```